# django-timezone-field gets error unicode object has no attribute zone

Tags: python, django, django-timezone, django-1.7

I was not able to do a migration on one of my model objects that use django-timezone-field in django 1.7

I found a solution here:  https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field/issues/12

I installed the forked version of django-time-field which fixed this problem:  https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field/issues/12

I now get the error:  `unicode object has no attribute zone` and `'unicode' object has no attribute 'localize'`

I am calling the field like this: `timezone.activate(customer.time_zone.zone)`

My model looks like:

```
from timezone_field import TimeZoneField

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="customer")
    time_zone = TimeZoneField()
```

If this fork is no good, how can I migrate?  Is there any other solution besides time zone field?

Answer (score 0):

This fork fixed it and seems to be the only version that works with django 1.7 https://github.com/anhtran/django-timezone-field